# phrases with preposition 'for'

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Is there any difference between the following two

1. I would hate for anyone to hack into my emails.
2. I would hate anyone to hack into my emails.

   I don't even know if the second is possible. I'm modeling it after 'I would like you to hack into my e-mail.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the first answer is idiomatic, the second is not.
In the case of "like", the word "for" isn't necessary, but it could be used: "I would like for you to hack into my emails."
This is just a usage difference between "like" and "hate".

Comment: But is the second one possible, how natural is it, if it is.

Comment: I would understand it if I  heard it, but I would find it unnatural.